# Захват объектов в потоке видео

Tags: распознавание, видео

Кто-нибудь писал программы для определения лица по видео, или что-то еще в таком духе? 
Мне интересно на чем лучше писать, может, сможете подсказать какие-нибудь ресурсы, где есть информация.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм Viola Jones и так называемые HaarCascades, в OpenCV всё для этого есть. Код для распознавания лиц есть в сэмплах OpenCV. Например, для Python: [OpenCV]/samples/python/facedetect.py. Вот простой код для детекции лиц на видео с камеры:

```
import cv
cascadePath = r"c:\OpenCV2.2\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
cascade = cv.Load(cascadePath)
memstorage = cv.CreateMemStorage()
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
outimage = None
name = 'window'
cv.NamedWindow(name)
while True:
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    key = cv.WaitKey(10)
    if(key != -1):
        break
    if not frame:
        break
    if outimage is None or cv.GetSize(frame) != cv.GetSize(outimage):
        outimage = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), 8, 3)
    cv.Flip(frame, outimage, 1)
    faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(outimage, cascade, memstorage)
    for rect, n in faces:
        cv.Rectangle(outimage, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), (255, 0, 0) )        
    cv.ShowImage(name, outimage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Цикл статей про распознавание номеров автомобилей. Это самое ближайшее что я видел.
http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/image_processing/114529/

Answer (score 0):

Начать лучше всего с теоретической или прикладной литературы по распознаванию образов, чтобы иметь общее представление о предмете. Обычно все сводится к разновидностям нейронных сетей.

Поскольку задача распознавания не нова, уже есть много готовых библиотек. Лично я сталкивался с [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) на C# - приличная библиотека. Еще есть [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) ([вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)) с поддержкой C/C++, Python.